# Запрос данных с сервера с помощью уникального ключа

Tags: java

Разработана программа на Java и теперь ее копии будут продаваться клиентам.

Каждому клиенту выдается уникальный ключ для работы программы.

**Задача:** не допустить распространение копий программы без оплаты лицензии.

Планируется на хостинге хранить данные, которые программа должна забрать, чтобы ее алгоритм запустился.

**Вопрос:** как реализовать обмен с хостингом, чтобы программа получала данные только в обмен на оплаченный ключ?

Comment: поднять машину, поставить сервер, клиент обращается серверу и запрашивает, а корректный ли я? сервер смотрит в БД и дает ответ. 
Самое простое, что в голову пришло. и конечно, же, это легко обойти

Comment: А есть возможность определять по мак-адресу? Или еще какой-то способ выделить конкретного пользователя и разрешить ему читать файл?

Comment: можно сделать авторизацию, но тут уже нужен доступ к серверу. По маку не хорошая идея, потому что мак можно изменить и работать как с лицензией

Comment: Программа собирает некоторые данные о железе машины, на этой основе генерирует ключ и запоминает. Далее юзер вводит свой ключ, идет сравнение. Если будет другая машина то и ключ там будет другой и не подойдет. Плюс: можно не использовать сервер, минус: клиенту придется работать на одной машине.

Comment: А если на том же компьютере, заказчик поменяет что-то из комплектухи?

Answer (score 1):

Все, что делается на клиенте - априори скомпрометировано, ему доверять нельзя какие бы "мега-шифрования" не использовали. Единственный выдомый мной способ защитить программу - не давать её. Давать доступ только по API с предварительной авторизацией к конкретному юзерю, т е сделать клиент-приложение бесполезным без данных и логики скрытой серверной части.

Answer (score 1):

Для защиты своего ПО мы используем Hasp ключи, в частности компании Sentinel.
В SDK идет утилита, которая оборачивает ваши бинарники/dll-so/jar своей оберткой делая так, что бы без вставленного в ПК hasp-а работа приложения была не возможна. Так же их обертка усложняет реверс-инженеринг кода. У них есть мощный API, который позволяет самостоятельно делать защиту работая с возможностями Hasp-ключа, но нам хватало пока и стандартного решения.
У них есть и сетевые решения, когда идет раздача лицензий через центр сертификации, а также есть так называемые сетевые ключи.
В России они представлены компанией [SafeNet](https://safenet-sentinel.ru/products/)
Думаю если вы посмотрите предлагаемые ими решения, вы сможете найти для себя подходящее.

P.S> Просьба не считать данный ответ данной рекламой, мы не один свой продукт защищали их решением (в том числе под ARM) и результаты нас более чем устраивают.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что приходит в голову - что-то наподобие [Denuvo](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denuvo), но, как показывает практика, эта технология не гарантирует 100% защиты. И мне кажется, что вы больше потеряете, чем приобретете.

Лучшее и проверенное решение на мой взгляд - это перенести логику вашего приложения на удаленный сервер, а вместо ключа использовать учетные записи. В этом случае приложение клиента сможет делать только то, что разрешит сервер для этой учетной записи.

Конечно, ничто не мешает передать учетную запись кому-то, но вы можете минимизировать потери, т.к. имеете больше контроля. Например, вы можете блокировать юзера, если под одной учетной записью одновременно авторизованы несколько клиентов.

Answer (score 0):

> Разработана программа на Java и теперь ее копии будут продаваться клиентам.
>    Как реализовать обмен с хостингом, чтобы программа получала данные только в обмен на оплаченный ключ?

А нельзя было подумать об этом перед разработкой?

Ладно, это все равно вопрос в пустоту.

Делается это так:

1. Есть авторизационный сервер, который при покупке проги выдает устройству токен
2. Прога с токеном в зубах стучится к серверу, где хранятся данные.
3. Сервер берет токен и обращается к авторизационному серверу и спрашивает - есть такой? Если есть выдает данные, если нет - извините.

Это крайне общая схема, которая должна быть модифицирована/усложнена следующим образом:

- Токен должен шифроваться на устройстве с ключом который генерируется с использованием идентификатора устройства, например [HardwareAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29)
- Токену надо установить срок жизни - скажем раз в неделю, то есть через неделю токен перегенерируется на новый прога обновляет свой токен